# How to find the size of a row in a table in databse(Sybase)

Tags: sap-ase, sap-iq

I  wanted to know the command to find the size of a row in a table in my database. Say I've a database `db` and a table `table`.

How can i find the size of a row in that database (which includes all the columns)?

Answer (score 2):

For Displaying the expected row size for a table See [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20020_1251/html/databases/databases312.htm)

Comment: select object_name(id), exp_rowsize from sysindexes where id > 100 and (indid = 0 or indid = 1) is `id` here one of the coloumn in that table , sysindexed is `table` What does object_name and exp_rowsize represent ?

Comment: select object_name(id), exp_rowsize from sysindexes where id > 100 and (indid = 0 or indid = 1) is id here one of the coloumn in that table , sysindexed is table What does object_name and exp_rowsize represent ?

Answer (score 0):

In ASE, I use a combination of sp_estspace and sp_spaceused for total Data / index sizing that I wrote myself.  You can grab the source for each inside sybsystemprocs.

sp_estspace tends to overestimate (by a lot) the size of the data (not indexes) and sp_spaceused divided by rowcount tends to not be a good indicator of how big a row *could* potentially be today (imagine you added 20 nullable columns yesterday and decide to use them, spaceused is unchanged).

1. reasonable expected data size = ((spaceused / rowcount) + estspace(1) ) / 2
2. I haven't done any analysis about the accuracy of either index commands, but I would imagine (spaceused / rowcount) would be very accurate for forward looking items.

It's not perfect by ANY means, but it's been a fairly reliable estimate for my purpose.  I wouldn't write any code that would break if it exceeded any of these estimates, though.